# Deploying Qt application on Windows/Linux, developing on MacOS

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, makefile, binary

I am trying to send my current program to a colleague. He's on Linux, I'm on MacOS. The result of my `release build` is an `.app` file. I would like to have a binary executable through `./binary`. There's a Makefile in the folder, but it throws `make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.`, so I guess I can't use that.

I am running Qt 5.4.1, Qt Creator 3.4.0. Compiling through GCC/CLANG.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you need to re-compile the program on Linux as it is not binary compatible to Mac OS X. Do you use a standard pro file?

Comment: @m.s. yes, I have a `.pro` file. Of course, I forgot. So I need a Makefile that compiles both on Linux and on a Mac.

Comment: the pro file does this for you! just run `qmake && make` on Linux

Comment: @m.s. ok! I'll give that a shot.